# Detecting phrases in two or more Javascript strings

Tags: javascript, string, phrases

I am wondering if there's an easy way to detect "phrases" in two strings without it being in quotes.  For example:

"i like jack in the box" and "jack in the box has good food"

In this case, "jack in the box" would be detected.  Now I could potentially go through the whole first string, see if it's in the second string, which it's not...  and keep cutting down to a smaller length and running it through the second string until I find the 3-word-match of "jack in the box"...  but it's not too efficient.

Any help would be great -- thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the wiki page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referring to the [Longest Common Subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) problem. This is used as the basis of a string comparison.

There are many SO questions relating to this problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=longest+common+subsequence

The algorithm isn't too hard to implement. Wikipedia has pseudocode that you can use as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks for defining my problem more clearly!  I appreciate it as well as the search link.